# window's bar title option TCL/TK

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is there a option for center the window's bar title ?
i use windows 10

I found nothing on this page:
[https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#M63)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no option to control the window title, other than the text and icon. The way the title appears (font, alignment, color) is not under control of tk. That is completely managed by the window manager.

Comment: thanks Bryan for the reply . I think it is a pity this function is currently not being performed.

Comment: @Mkn Perhaps you can tell us what the Windows API call to use for this is, the counterpart to [`SetWindowText()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633546(v=vs.85).aspx) that we currently use?

Comment: @DonalFellows , how to call this function of User32.dll ? and edit the entries ? thanks in advance