# Apply colour to menu and title bar

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to change the default colour of menu bar (and title). What would be the right approach?
As I understood, changing title bar color is at the moment not possible [window's bar title option TCL/TK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38808635/windows-bar-title-option-tcl-tk) are there some workarounds in windows?

I tried without sucess to change the colour of atleast the menu bar. Below is a sample code

```
package require Tk

#§§§§§
# Start: Icons 
#§§§§§
image create photo Icon_Exit -data {
    iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAFMN540AAAABGdBTUEAAYagMeiWXwAAA8tJ
    REFUSInFl01PG1cUhp87H0YVoMYZ27iVYAHlo2LTSpSEdFFIpULFRxYhP6C/IV11ESVZ5G9U
    lbozrVSgLaYL3A0xKVIjRbQBGioRBRuPjasAauJh5mYx2MT22GMgVd+Vfee+57zn3HPPmYEK
    CIDgD7syX3AAUADyBQc5HT1ZABAz6Up2EbGUJJaSfz63pHFz8bYCsD0e5v149sRGx49muVti
    KellzUg+uqO8viCnozwdD8Nr27Xij7XPQohYGgTIG9GSTAFg3Fy87eXCaQokagXjspVvt6XT
    pHs+LIm7YhxvkJTElR4WHOhpVdmdihQDPlG9mi3wZCLC1HK+2uyza210/WySLzioogFBWvDh
    +l2k9EynANC+fiId3ZtdC8GH63c1AEfXqeW6JqSUSuXa4EUdOR3lcjFvtmR7PMzORASccvVa
    JfnBnoWYSdPdqiKno2wd2nTMm26AiqhPRsLTiTABRSBiaQYu6sgbUfriWdb3j3zIQPtcxvUi
    YDXvKqlwWoMsAFG90/E8rHNAGF/+cif/Qe+t05AUy+Loiy6hIWXN8vI1ciaWJ1nCH6OhspsO
    buGEmqr9VJAlLZpgZzICtmthIKizctWgp0X1ISuCjnkTBdi51sZ7LSq/fWowtJRjOWf5kAEE
    ROcy/GtLNsfC9MZNkh5EbzJwydDpbFbZOrRJfGKUQvAld7eoJK+6Urt+MhHHIVQmsYqsCtgY
    C9MXz7pSBbwzlwFgbSxURS6rbVuC9l26XKWAd2d33XoXdchFA9X6PK5UpezTQnOaAgkj+eh0
    LCFEjuKA/CoxrBSskVot9o1BCOEE9KX8veGEBqC8LAznP+y7ddab2SiUlxbB3x9LIHGuXJ9L
    hO8O6dZsQ73TkW4xNbC1rmNVwNpoiKPrUZ5NtdHbqnkble6435lqw74eZW0sVBreZ3JsS+iP
    Z+lZMHGk5PFoiN2piDs8j184BoI6qckI66NhAPriWfoXsrVaRwmeI64MAjYPbNpnM1wKB4gN
    XeD+iMHWoQ1AZ7NK6oXD5aUcK5mCmyafaH0jLoMqWMlZjCT22Dw4orNZpbNZ5e9Dm+Ffc6xk
    LXzze2rHxylNT0b46/MwLZpCb9yke8FEV2B9NFx+BA2gfqodyWAowMzQBdrfclM6tJQjWUwp
    0D6bYSAU4Psr7hGkXjhM38+zbBZq9kt/x0KwsX/EviX5OJljOeu2/7KUqoLVvEXHvMmgofPN
    R2+zcWB7vs2cwjH8Y0n6F7Ol//X2PtizSp8RfgX2v3UuN2IhhGJ5D/w3CcWyQPicwX+NVw59
    Zhn1SGGgAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
}
image create photo Icon_Resize -data {
    iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB4AAAAeCAYAAAFMN540AAAABGdBTUEAAYagMeiWXwAAAxxJ
    REFUSIntlj1oFEEUx3+7lzuNJzEj2ogflakEScBCC3UQxWhhZ4hgpyBqISjIgoE0Mo3YCQHt
    Dk60S6EBTVxioWUQBEFQVBCUE8fPJN4luxY7k8ztbe5Oo5X+4Zh7b/b/PmbevBloBhGEZd/8
    iY1u0Espsnk9ruwDm12KD+RcO9aoANYD64Ai0AGglRyzdnc5Pl6bsWpNAqw0yldayS1Gl2+a
    ZVuwAfYAFeCTVrJ+BUQQDmQxbWDbzEeb0gsBcEkEYUzMaANdBOE1M9alYZmnm2/Fn4bnxNUD
    9BpxCjgODAMjWsmTIgjLWsljdgSzmwYVYEor+dzIQyIIJ4zhSa3kHqMvWYJL/gR8SUW2hhgP
    jz5HN55FlsBh4Lzx9jLy2fr5spx3UvO0kjUr+9TDcwU/wh4Rz/3ekdvHb5H+Ctx97tdKjjnj
    fpKV3Qk8IzmwABWtpIb6BTueGo+a+X5D7DW/9aQhgrDcKkwRhANut3H3uZT6cBRYbcQpreQF
    krKtZJFHgYIjn/WJuyK8p6nUxoBHUJ9z0fW8yq9+jPCe+vH8dkc9DDzO8lwVQbggTEdQqM10
    VfOd3cA3ox4BbgP3XUcNTbmdzpCu7aYQQVgWQdifFXZL2CZg4VZYVpgF4DtwhMXiKS1cBf9R
    h+U0jlbchklTAneBm7bFA4PAIdMiqiS3rj1CVaCmlSy04rYdpQjCXLtZLIe7kLEIwnipltTK
    gDtvDlHsHiSLlkYaXh00PeYP7UW6FHdJx6bN3wNuaCVPLkXccC4sznQyCfQBb4GNwAOt5D7H
    1nXgBHBAK1nXtLJayDimcNJvnvnYj4q5H8XZKD8+AzuIeVKYm+6q5lcJ4E2GrVPAaWAuPZHl
    WAITwFfgA05zzHlRNBvlNwEdhRrd76/Iz2bqG4uPQ3eJh4GLwF7MBdHMsUVJK3kmrRRB+ArY
    Us0znUVK7WvJOHyW/u6XWv1voJekUTfc5M0y3i2C8CqwwtHNAmutYM7qCPBOKzlkbvthYFQr
    eatZRFmOp4CDQC1jDuAOyUrZgrlNcg1B8lIoAS8cW19wXhD/Ln4CQ7A8G4GVhN4AAAAASUVO
    RK5CYII=
}
#
#§§§§§
# End: Icons 
#§§§§§
#§§§§§
# Start: Menu Bar
#§§§§§
menu .menu_bar 
. configure -menu .menu_bar
menu .level_0 -tearoff 0
.menu_bar add cascade -menu .level_0 -label "Menu" -underline 0 
.level_0 add command -label "Resize App" -command {Resize_Win1} \
-image                 Icon_Resize   -compound left
#
.level_0 add separator
.level_0 add command -label Exit -underline 0 -command {exit} \
-image                 Icon_Exit  -compound left  

.menu_bar configure -bg black -activebackground black \
-fg white -activeforeground white ;# effects not visible on GUI
#§§§§§
# End: Menu Bar
#§§§§§
```

Comment: If changing the `-background` option doesn't work, then you'll need to fake one up in the *very old* way with a frame and menubuttons. It will look a bit wrong on Windows, and very wrong on macOS.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setsyscolors is the winapi function. The counterpart is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsyscolor. But this is in C++ (can be done in standard C)  so not sure if this helps.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Don't want to redo the entire app, too much work

Comment: @InhirCode: Have no background in either c or c++.

Comment: That would mean I need to restyle the app in such a way that the default menus "blend in" with the colours.  Can't call this workaround a solution ... But have no other options